# One-column MySQL result to array

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL query to column: `SELECT column FROM table`. Is there any possibility  how I can save result of this query to array?

I have now this code:

```
    $dotazHlasy = mysql_query("SELECT `id_ulohy` FROM `mproud-hlasy` WHERE `id_uzivatele`=".$_SESSION['uzivatel']) or die(mysql_error()); 
  while($radek = mysql_fetch_row($dotazHlasy)){
    $hlasy[] = $radek;
  };
```

This return to me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

)
```

I would like get this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 4

        [1] => 3

    )
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: can you show us what youve tried so far? At the moment youve only posted the sql part, can we see the php that calls it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Or, `$hlasy[] = $radek[0];`

Comment: Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of `mysql_*`, since it is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to put one column in array as the following code.

```
$YouArray = array();
$command = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM table");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($command))
    $YouArray[] = $result['column'];
```